# putExtra using for loop in Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri requestUrl = Uri.parse(url);
String pContent = requestUrl.toString().split("share://")[1];
String pasteData = pContent+"";

share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("message/rfc822");
share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
//String septline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
//pasteData= pasteData.replaceAll("<br />", "\n");
Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),pasteData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setMargin(50,50);
toast.show();
String [] parts = pasteData.split("<br />");
for (String part : parts){
         share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, part);
}
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share On"));
```

I want for loop should write share.putextra for each part, but here putextra is only once with value of last part only

ans shuld be like this

```
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, part1);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, part2);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, part3);
```

Comment: Actually, the main problem is , i want to share three line(first line \n second line \n third line ) on whatsapp hike mail text etc; but newLine is not supporting thats why i want to share these complete sentence into pieces not in single line but as a different line

Answer (score 3):

> You are doing it wrong, In Intent every key is unique, so if you try
>   to put any data with same key, it's gonna be overrided.

So in your code as you're running a loop, and Intent key is same in the loop, so it's getting overridden, and you are getting only last value.

To resolve this problem , try putting data with different keys.

For more information please visit [Android developer page](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri requestUrl = Uri.parse(url);
String pContent = requestUrl.toString().split("share://")[1];
String pasteData = pContent+"";

share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("message/rfc822");
share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
//String septline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
//pasteData= pasteData.replaceAll("<br />", "\n");
Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),pasteData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setMargin(50,50);
toast.show();
String [] parts = pasteData.split("<br />");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String part : parts){
         sb.append(part);
}

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share On"));
```

Comment: He is not sending data to his other activity, he wants to share data using intent to any application which is capable of handling Intent type "message/rfc822"

Answer (score 0):

You have to set all data at once you can use string builder with break/n then provide it once to you intent.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String [] parts = pasteData.split("<br />");
for (String part : parts){
         sb.append(part);
}
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

**yes i got the ans, thanks all for your support and ideas**
this how we can add new line to content for(email, hike, text message, hangout, whatsapp).

```
if (url.startsWith("share://")) {

            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            Uri requestUrl = Uri.parse(url);
            String pContent = requestUrl.toString().split("share://")[1];
            String pasteData = pContent+"";
            share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),pasteData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setMargin(50,50);
            toast.show();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String [] parts = pasteData.split("<br />");
            for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                String part = parts[i];
                sb.append(part);
                sb.append('\n');
            }
            share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, (Serializable) sb);

            //share.setType("message/rfc822");
            //share.setType("text/plain");
            share.setType("*/*");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share On"));
            return true;
```